# remove products of a category from the total count cart woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product-quantity

I building my ecommerce for sell wine with wordpress 4.2.2 and woocommerce 2.3.11.
I created a custom function for end the order only with bottles on multiple of 6.
Until this I don't have any problem, but I have 2 categories with packages of 6 bottles, so I want to avoid that this 2 categories will count in the quantity total items cart.
I'm not expert with php so I try to create a function that check if the each item is inside the category and if belong to one package category, subtract one item.
This work good only if there is one item of this 2 categories, but if I add 2 packages on the cart, only one will be subtract.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'woocommerce_check_cart_quantities' );
function woocommerce_check_cart_quantities() {
$total_products = WC()->cart->cart_contents_count;
$multiples = 6;
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $prodotti = $values['data'];
    $terms = get_the_terms ($prodotti->id, 'product_cat');
    foreach ($terms as $term){
        $categoria = $term->term_id;
    }   

    if (($categoria == 169) || ($categoria == 152)) {
            $pacchetti = $values ['quantity'];  
            $totale = ($total_products-$pacchetti);
    } else {
        $totale = $total_products;
    }
}
echo $totale;
if ( ( $totale % $multiples ) > 0 )
    wc_add_notice( sprintf( __('You need to buy in quantities of 6 products', 'woocommerce'), $multiples ), 'error' );

}
```

Desired Counting:

[image: Screen 1 - Right Counting]

Existing Counting

[image: Screen 2 - Wrong counting]

I'm open for every solution for make this works.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: I will have to think about this more, but what about using [Product Bundles](https://www.woothemes.com/products/product-bundles/) for the items that need to be sold in packages of 6?

Comment: Hi again :). The product bundles dosen't works at all :(, also with your previously help. I also hire a freelance but without succesfull. So I abandoned the idea to use it and I work a lot for find another solution since today with the code above.

Comment: Why doesn't Product Bundles work? Based on your description it seems like exactly your use case. And unfortunately you can't always hire a good freelancer. That has happened to me before too. For WooCommerce-specific projects you would probably do well to hire a [Woo Expert](https://www.woothemes.com/experts/).

Comment: Now, about your question... To clarify: the total cart quantity must always be in multiples of 6? So you could buy 3 bottles of red wine and 3 bottles of white wine? But the La Ns selection is a bundle of 6 already and should not count towards that total? Let me see what I can come up with.

Comment: About product bundels has the problem that count also the bundle on the total items in the cart.
Anyway... exactly the single bottles must be buy always in mutliples of 6 (for a deal with our carrier).
But we have also this two categories:
- confezioni = category id 152
- bag in box = category id 169
In this 2 categories we create group of products (always 6/12 bottles for a product) so a customer be able to buy also only one item from this 2 categories.

Comment: With my code the count is right, but only if I add only 1 product of this 2 categories. If I add in the cart more than 1 product of this categories, only 1 is subtract (always the last one in the cart list).

Comment: I think I got it. Please test out my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks pretty good to me. I think the one thing you are missing is the [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) function to more reliably test which products are in your two special categories.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'woocommerce_check_cart_quantities' );
function woocommerce_check_cart_quantities() {
    $total_products = WC()->cart->cart_contents_count;
    $multiples = 6;
    $totale = 0;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $prodotti = $values['data'];

        if( ! has_term( array( 169, 152 ), 'product_cat', $prodotti->id ) ){
            $totale += $values['quantity'];
        } 

    }
    echo $totale;
    if ( ( $totale % $multiples ) > 0 ){
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __('You need to buy in multiples of %d products', 'your-textdomain'), $multiples ), 'error' );
    }

}
```

Comment: AMAZING! This works great!

Because you save my life tonight I will buy you a margarita :)

If can I ask... why my code dosen't works? (I wanna learn as much as I can)

Comment: Great! Don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer. And thank you for that margarita. If I had to guess why your code didn't work, I think it could be the `foreach()` loop. If your product is in multiple categories then `$categoria = $term->term_id;` is arbitrarily whatever the last category in `$terms`. And that would make your `if()` statement unreliable.

Comment: ahhh ok ok understand! Thank you again